# Content Editable bug: select all text then type and only the first letter appears

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, contenteditable

There seems to be a bug on Chrome with content editable anchors. In my below snippet, if you select all the text `Foo` by double clicking the text and then start typing in new text, only the first letter you type is added to the anchor. All other text is not added.

Is anyone aware of a solution, fix, workaround to this problem?

Additional Information:

- Chrome version: Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows 10.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="">
  <a href="#" contenteditable="true"><span>Foo</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems any element inside the anchor tag is restricting it to be edited. If you remove the span, it works without issues.